# Redirection in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

I've found a code for redirecting to the coming soon page using .htaccess.
The code works but the subscription form won't work:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Maintenance page redirection
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
 #  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/notify$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js) [NC]
  RewriteRule .* /notify [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Sorry if this question sounds basic but how can I redirect every page to /notify except /home/submit_notify ?

While I'm on the subject does anyone know any lessons to learn .htaccess from scratch? Every one I've found seems to depend on you already knowing the basics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an extra condition to exclude `/home/submit_notify`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/submit_notify 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/notify$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js) [NC]
  RewriteRule .* /notify [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

> While I'm on the subject does anyone know any lessons to learn .htaccess from scratch? Every one I've found seems to depend on you already knowing the basics.

I think it's best to just trial and error. Get yourself a local apache install and some test directories and htaccess files and try different things. Or try to solve some of the mod_rewrite questions on Stack Overflow